# How to make a stacked bar to visualize a time sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I track where my time goes and I want to vizualize it. I have a csv formatted like this:

9:00 AM, 9:45 AM, 45, Browsing Superuser

9:45 AM, 10:00 AM, 15, Asking my question

..and so on.

The first column is starting time, second is ending time, third is duration in minutes, and fourth is a description of what was done in that period.

Is there a way to turn it into a graph that would look like the daily display in most calendar apps. I would describe it as single axis graph with the values being the hour and minute of the day, and the entries look like a stacked bar (column). Here's a picture:

[image: Daily agenda]

I am aware that there are dozen time tracking apps out there but I'm not 100% satisfied with none of them, so I'm building my own Excel dashboard. This is just part of it.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to chart the duration column and select the stacked style you prefer. If you had dates as a column in your data you could show breakdown for several days for comparison.
A more useful display of the proportion of time spent on different things (rather than chronological) might be achieved by categorising your time use and charting totals (use a Pivot to aggregate the raw data).

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).